# Impl в rust. Как вызываются self-функции внутри Implementation?

Tags: rust

Возник вопрос, касательно использования ранее описанных функций внутри одной имплементации.

Для примера - есть такой код

```
pub struct test {
    Id: i32,
}

impl test {
    pub fn new() -> i32 {
        return 1
    }

    pub fn ret_new(&self) {
       let t = self.new(); // Error while run
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы избежать использования полного пути крейта и вызвать функцию `new()` из `ret_new()` с помощью `self`. Обращение к переменным структуры спокойно проходит, но не к функциям. В документации не увидел подобного примера. Такое вообще возможно?

Comment: `test::new()` или `Self::new()`

Comment: Обратите внимание на то что вы по факту обращаетесь к статической функции